# Microsoft Excel -> How to apply color to alternating rows, but not to a certain column (via a formula)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

So it is explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-color-to-alternate-rows-or-columns-30002ce0-7a1c-4d70-a70c-4b6232f09f5e) by Microsoft Support how to apply a colour to alternating rows, using a formula:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=0
```

However, what if we want to, in the formula as well (not via the selection) specify 1 specific column X within the solution to which the colour should not be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, replacing `X` with the number of the column: `A`=`1`, `B`=`2`, and so on...

```
=AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,COLUMN()<>X)
```

In action:
[image]

Comment: Here is another question with regards to alternating row colours, if you are in the mood. :) https://superuser.com/questions/1583038/microsoft-excel-how-to-apply-color-to-alternating-rows-but-only-to-those-row

Comment: With regards to the answer above, I am yielding an error: 'There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? ...' --- I think because some PCs use a comma as a seperation mark, and other PCs use a semicolon ... this is very cumbersome, but not your fault. --- Hope I can find a fix ... is this specifically set within the Excel sheet you think, or just depends on your Excel/PCs settings?

Comment: Yes you'll have to change the `,` to `;` depending on your Excel installation.