# Microsoft Excel -> How to apply color to alternating rows, but only to columns X and Y (via a formula)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

So it is explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-color-to-alternate-rows-or-columns-30002ce0-7a1c-4d70-a70c-4b6232f09f5e) by Microsoft Support how to apply a colour to alternating rows, using a formula:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=0
```

However, what if we want to, in the formula as well (not via the selection) specify 2 specific columns X and Y within the solution to which the colour should **ONLY** be applied (i.e. the alternating colouring should not be applied to other columns of the rows)?

P.S.: Please note this is a bit the opposite of an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744394/microsoft-excel-how-to-apply-color-to-alternating-rows-but-not-to-a-certain) which was first answered by @BigBen, which asked for excluding certain columns

Comment: @BigBen :) Here's another variety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to your previous question:

```
=AND(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,OR(COLUMN()=X, COLUMN()=Y))
```

In your case, change the `,` to `;`.

In action:
[image]